# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS take 100 seconds to boot (maybe problem with mount sda9 and ASPM r8169)

Tags: boot, mount, suspend, ethernet, realtek

I have Ubuntu on my HP laptop in dual boot,and it takes always more than 100 seconds to boot. I read a lot about this problem but I didn't solve.

The system has 2 problem:

- Mounting my **sda6**: which is a partition used by Windows too (in dual boot). (if I mount in read only mode it works).
  It says is used by windows so I need to arrest without hibernating but I didn't hibernate at all. Can it be related to Dropbox? Maybe it locks the partition because I have my Dropbox synced folder in there.

But, IMPORTANT: This partition doesn't mount on boot.

- **Suspending**:
  When I suspend and restart the PC, I'll get an rfkill (hard) on my Ethernet  and there's no way to get it work.

So I guessed these problems affects also booting time.

**dmesg**

```
... Something related r8192 I didn't understand

[    0.000000] PERCPU: Embedded 33 pages/cpu @ffff88025ec00000 s98008 r8192 d28968 u262144
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s98008 r8192 d28968 u262144 alloc=1*2097152

... r8169: can't disable ASPM (I can't enable ASPM OS control in the BIOS)

[    1.490373] r8169 Gigabit Ethernet driver 2.3LK-NAPI loaded
[    1.490382] r8169 0000:09:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[    1.498332] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eth0: RTL8168g/8111g at 0xffffc90000cfc000, 3c:a8:2a:a7:33:a2, XID 10900800 IRQ 49
[    1.498338] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 9200 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]

.... I think this is fine (?) 

[    1.525885] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eno1: renamed from eth0


.... Here's the delay gap: from 26 to 98. Bluetooth sometimes is executed before the gap. r8169 error is always after the gap!    

[   26.275773] audit: type=1400 audit(1482416408.361:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed" pid=816 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   98.081272] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   98.081275] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   98.081277] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   98.281688] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eno1: rtl_counters_cond == 1 (loop: 1000, delay: 10).
[   99.960029] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eno1: rtl_counters_cond == 1 (loop: 1000, delay: 10).
[  100.824246] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eno1: rtl_counters_cond == 1 (loop: 1000, delay: 10).
[  102.048226] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eno1: rtl_counters_cond == 1 (loop: 1000, delay: 10).
[  102.048397] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eno1: link is not ready
[  102.166721] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eno1: link down
```

**lhsw** (Ethernet)

```
  description: Ethernet interface
            product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
            vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
            logical name: eno1
            version: 10
            serial: 3c:a8:2a:a7:33:a2
            size: 10Mbit/s
            capacity: 1Gbit/s
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
            configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
            resources: irq:49 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:c6004000-c6004fff memory:c6000000-c6003fff
```

Thaks in advance!

EDIT:
I disinstalled the r8169 module and compiled the one from Realtek and istalled it, but it doesn't change my situation. 
I also read about swap partition causing slow boot, I deleted mine and it doesn't change.

My hard drive is pationed like this:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 698,7 GiB, 750156374016 bytes, 1465149168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: DB62AEEC-501C-49B6-BE41-23DBDFBDD4EF

Dispositivo      Start       Fine   Settori   Size Tipo
/dev/sda1         2048    1333247   1331200   650M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2      1333248    1865727    532480   260M EFI System
/dev/sda3      1865728    2127871    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4      2127872  573872127 571744256 272,6G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5    795465728  797296639   1830912   894M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda6    797296640 1411694591 614397952   293G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda7   1411696640 1413511167   1814528   886M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda8   1413511168 1465137151  51625984  24,6G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda9    590665728  795465727 204800000  97,7G Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

sda9 is the Linux partition, sda6 is files shared partition between windows and ubuntu (sometimes it doesn't mount in read write mode, but it doessn't mount booting) and the others are windows partitions..